# PHP - Nested For Each Issues

Tags: php, foreach, nested

So todays not going well in the world of PHP for fun, I'm having some issues with nested for loops in PHP - I've read somewhere that your not really meant to do this however in other places I see examples of it.

```
foreach ($xml->result->rowset->row as $row){
    $getMailID = $row{'messageID'};
    $body = $row;
    echo "MailIDCheck: " .$getMailID;
    echo $body;
    foreach ($mailMessage as &$rows){
        if($rows['mailID'] == $getMailID){
            $rows['mailMsg'] = $body;
        }
    }
}
```

The echo's are in there for testing. However where I think it should output the $getMailID and the $body at the first loop through, then go through the next foreach find the matching one and update the $rows['mailMsg']. Then start the process over again, however it doesn't seem to be doing that, it seems to be doing them all before it even hits that second, nested for each and I can't figure out why.

Any help to restore my sanity is MUCH appreciated,

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Where does `$mailMessage` defined?

Comment: Is `$row{'messageID'}` just a typo in the question? PHP doesn't use curly braces like that.

Comment: The inner loop doesn't print anything, how can you tell that not doing them at the right time?

Comment: @Barmar - I have output at the bottom of this PHP file;
foreach ($mailMessage as $row){
 echo "</br>Number: " .$row{'mailNumber'};
 echo "</br>ID: " .$row{'mailID'};
 echo "</br>Date: " .$row{'mailDate'};
 echo "</br>Sender: " .$row{'mailSender'};
 echo "</br>Message: " .$row{'mailMsg'}."</br>";
}

Comment: @Ofir Baruch - It's defined above as an empty array which I populate before hitting this function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're showing with that code. Are you saying that the contents of `$mailMessage` are incorrect when the above code is all done? Can you post `var_dump($xml->result->rowset->row)` and `var_dump($mailMessage)` before and after the loop?

Comment: @Barmar PHP indeed supports this alternate array syntax using `{}` curly braces see here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#99015, although I would advise to always use `[]` brackets

Comment: @IvanHušnjak Yeah, I tried it and discovered that it works, to my surprise, but it was too late for me to delete my comment.

Comment: @Barmar I've pasted the full thing on pastebin so it's there in its entirety - http://pastebin.com/qFWSVLNL - The contents of $mailMessage are not being updated the way I thought they would be - I can't understand why not though. - The print at the end of the file - to me - should print out the ID's and the date ect followed by the messages. - The echo's in the middle showing i'm getting the right data However I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong about updating the array to put that in the ['mailMsg'] field. - Thanks

Comment: `$rows['mailID']` is an XMLElement object, `$getMailID` is a string. So the comparisons never succeed.

Comment: @Barmar $rows['mailID'] is suppost to be coming form the array data that is stored above. Is this definitely the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
    if((string)$rows['mailID'] == (string)$getMailID){
```

Both `$rows['mailID']` and `$getMailID` are `SimpleXMLElement` objects. You need to compare their string values.

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have been stuck with that forever! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Liberal use of `var_dump()` is your friend.